# How to read the latest line from the csv file using ReadLineAsync method?

Tags: c#, csv

This is my code to read the csv file asynchronoulsy using ReadLineAsync() function from the [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-8.0) class but it reads first line only of the [csv file](https://github.com/addy1997/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/main/iothub/device/samples/solutions/PnpDeviceSamples/Robot/Data/Robots_data.csv)

```
    private async Task ReadAndSendJointDataFromCSVFileAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
     Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
     sw.Start();

     string filePath = @ "/home/adwait/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/iothub/device/samples/solutions/PnpDeviceSamples/Robot/Data/Robots_data.csv";

     using(StreamReader oStreamReader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filePath))) {
       string sFileLine = await oStreamReader.ReadLineAsync();

       string[] jointDataArray = sFileLine.Split(',');

       // Assuming the joint data is processed in parallel
       var tasks = new List < Task > ();

       // Process joint pose
       tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {
         var jointPose = jointDataArray.Take(7).Select(Convert.ToSingle).ToArray();
         var jointPoseJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jointPose);
         await SendTelemetryAsync("JointPose", jointPoseJson, cancellationToken);
       }));

       // Process joint velocity
       tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {
         var jointVelocity = jointDataArray.Skip(7).Take(7).Select(Convert.ToSingle).ToArray();
         var jointVelocityJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jointVelocity);
         await SendTelemetryAsync("JointVelocity", jointVelocityJson, cancellationToken);
       }));

       // Process joint acceleration
       tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {
         var jointAcceleration = jointDataArray.Skip(14).Take(7).Select(Convert.ToSingle).ToArray();
         var jointAccelerationJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jointAcceleration);
         await SendTelemetryAsync("JointAcceleration", jointAccelerationJson, cancellationToken);
       }));

       // Process external wrench
       tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {
         var externalWrench = jointDataArray.Skip(21).Take(6).Select(Convert.ToSingle).ToArray();
         var externalWrenchJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(externalWrench);
         await SendTelemetryAsync("ExternalWrench", externalWrenchJson, cancellationToken);
       }));

       await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
     }

     sw.Stop();
     _logger.LogDebug(String.Format("Elapsed={0}", sw.Elapsed));
   }
```

Basically, the csv file has 10128 lines. I want to read the latest line which gets added to the csv file.

How do I do it?

Using File.ReadLine(filePath) throws this exception

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.PathTooLongException: The path
> '/home/adwait/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/iothub/device/samples/solutions/PnpDeviceSamples/Robot/-2.27625e-06,-0.78542,-3.79241e-06,-2.35622,5.66111e-06,3.14159,0.785408,0.00173646,-0.0015847,0.000962475,-0.00044469,-0.000247682,-0.000270337,0.000704195,0.000477503,0.000466693,-6.50664e-05,0.00112044,-2.47425e-06,0.000445592,-0.000685786,1.21642,-0.853085,-0.586162,-0.357496,-0.688677,0.230229' is too long, or a component of the specified path is too long.

```
private async Task ReadAndSendJointDataFromCSVFileAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
  Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
  sw.Start();

  string filePath = @ "/home/adwait/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/iothub/device/samples/solutions/PnpDeviceSamples/Robot/Data/Robots_data.csv";

  using(StreamReader oStreamReader = new StreamReader(File.ReadLines(filePath).Last())) {
    string sFileLine = await oStreamReader.ReadLineAsync();

    string[] jointDataArray = sFileLine.Split(',');

    // Assuming the joint data is processed in parallel
    var tasks = new List < Task > ();

    // Process joint pose
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {
      var jointPose = jointDataArray.Take(7).Select(Convert.ToSingle).ToArray();
      var jointPoseJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jointPose);
      await SendTelemetryAsync("JointPose", jointPoseJson, cancellationToken);
    }));

    // Process joint velocity
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {
      var jointVelocity = jointDataArray.Skip(7).Take(7).Select(Convert.ToSingle).ToArray();
      var jointVelocityJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jointVelocity);
      await SendTelemetryAsync("JointVelocity", jointVelocityJson, cancellationToken);
    }));

    // Process joint acceleration
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {
      var jointAcceleration = jointDataArray.Skip(14).Take(7).Select(Convert.ToSingle).ToArray();
      var jointAccelerationJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jointAcceleration);
      await SendTelemetryAsync("JointAcceleration", jointAccelerationJson, cancellationToken);
    }));

    // Process external wrench
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {
      var externalWrench = jointDataArray.Skip(21).Take(6).Select(Convert.ToSingle).ToArray();
      var externalWrenchJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(externalWrench);
      await SendTelemetryAsync("ExternalWrench", externalWrenchJson, cancellationToken);
    }));

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
  }

  sw.Stop();
  _logger.LogDebug(String.Format("Elapsed={0}", sw.Elapsed));
}
```

Comment: Have you considered `File.ReadLines(filePath).Last()`?

Comment: Or `Task.Run(() => File.ReadLines(filePath).Last());`?

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for your reply. Using File.ReadLines() throws this exception - updated the question above.

Comment: Come on. Did you actually read that error message? That's not really name of your file, is it? That looks like you've appended one of the lines from the file to the folder path. Maybe show the new code you used rather than just the error message, so we can see what you did wrong. Of course, you should have been able to see that the file name was wrong and fix it yourself by debugging.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, Yeah, that's the error message I read. I've not appended anything. Please find the updated code above

Comment: @Astroboy - The code shows that the file name should be `"/home/adwait/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/iothub/device/samples/solutions/PnpDeviceSamples/Robot/Data/Robots_data.csv"` and that's vastly different from the path in the exception. Please show us the real code you're using.

Comment: @Enigmativity, here's [link](https://github.com/addy1997/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/b93b6f38ddb874ad309f88583d36fc26fffe01b5/iothub/device/samples/solutions/PnpDeviceSamples/Robot/RobotSample.cs#L102-#L159) to the complete code. Sorry! I couldn't paste it in the section above

Comment: if (File.Exists(filePath)) string sFileLine = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).LastOrDefault(); (if code can reach to the file)

Comment: the excepiton you show doesn't have anything to do wit reading whatever part of the file. It's just that you are passing an invalid filename.  Don't know where that comes from, but fix your code generating the filename ...

Comment: `new StreamReader(File.ReadLInes(filePath).Last()))` reads the last line from the file and interprets its content as file name for the `StreamReader` constructor.

Comment: If you're calling File.ReadLines, which you should, then you do NOT use a StreamReader. Think about what you're writing. What do you think File.ReadLines does? It's reads the lines of a file. What do you think Last does? It gets the last item in a sequence; the last line of the file in this case. Why would you then pass the that last line to a StreamReader?

Comment: @jmcilhinney, exactly passing last line to stream reader doesn't make sense because its already being read by the ReadLines() function which points towards the last line in the csv now.

Comment: And you've misstyped the code I posted in the comments. `File.ReadLInes(filePath).Last()` is wrong. You should copy-and-paste, not retype. You should also only post code you've actually run. You're asking us to fix basic syntax errors otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slow (but reliable) method is to read all of the lines in the file and return the last one. Something like:

```cs
static string? GetLastLine(string filename)
{
    using StreamReader reader = new(filename);
    string? last = null;
    while (reader.ReadLine() is string line)
        last = line;
    return last;
}
```

Of course this allocates a lot of strings for no good reason, and the GC will have to get rid of them all shortly afterwards. Not ideal, but that's how it goes. (The `async` version is simple enough to make, but this runs in a few ms per MB. Up to you.)

To get it to go faster you can try just reading the last part of the file - enough to get a couple of lines - and process that. You'll need to know the maximum line length for this, just so you can guarantee that you get at least one full line. Assuming that you're working with ASCII or UTF8 data you can probably do something like this:

```cs
static string? GetLastLine(string filename, int maxLineLength)
{
    using Stream stream = File.OpenRead(filename);
    stream.Position = stream.Length - maxLineLength * 3 / 2;
    using StreamReader reader = new(stream);
    string? last = null;
    while (reader.ReadLine() is string line)
        last = line;
    return last;
}
```

(This should work in fairly constant time regardless of the size of the file, since it will always process the same amount of data - about 100 microseconds on my machine for a 1MB file using `maxLineLength = 150`. Again, conversion to `async` version is simple.)

And finally, if you're expecting lines to be added to the file over time and you want to just read the fresh lines from the file, keep track of the file size and resume reading from there when the file size changes.

---

As pointed out in the comments, the above isn't particularly useful if you want to read new lines as they come in from outside your program. Not only does it always return the last line of the file, regardless of changes, but if multiple lines are added you'll only get the last one. Almost certainly not what you want.

What you probably want is a way to read new lines as they come in, and not skip any new lines. This means tracking changes in the file's length and resuming read one line at a time. You don't want to lock the file too long, and since `StreamReader` buffers ahead you can't rely on `stream.Position` to line up with the end of the line you just read.

The solution is to read all the lines you can each time and save them for subsequent reads. We can pull new lines into a `Queue<>` and track the file's size to detect when there's more to read. Something like this:

```cs
sealed class LineReader
{
    // File to read from.
    private readonly string _filename;
    
    // Queue for when multiple new lines are added between reads.
    private readonly Queue<string> _queue = new();
    
    // Length of file after last read.
    private long _lastPosition;
    
    // True if there's something to read.
    public bool LinesAvailable
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_queue.Count > 0)
                return true;
            FileInfo fi = new(_filename);
            return fi.Exists && fi.Length != _lastPosition;
        }
    }
    
    public LineReader(string filename, bool readExistingLines = false)
    {
        _filename = filename;
        FileInfo fi = new(_filename);
        _lastPosition = readExistingLines || !fi.Exists ? 0 : fi.Length;
    }
    
    // Returns when a line is read or token is cancelled.
    public async Task<string?> WaitNextLineAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (_queue.TryDequeue(out string? queued))
                return queued;
            if (await GetNextLineAsync() is string line)
                return line;
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(20, token);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    // Read next line, or `null` if none available.
    public async Task<string?> GetNextLineAsync()
    {
        if (_queue.TryDequeue(out string? line))
            return line;
        
        // Check if file length has changed.
        FileInfo fi = new(_filename);
        if (!fi.Exists || fi.Length == _lastPosition)
            return null;
        
        // Open the stream. May fail if file is locked.
        Stream stream;
        try
        {
            stream = fi.OpenRead();
        }
        catch 
        {
            return null;
        }
        
        using (stream)
        {
            // If file is smaller assume it was cleared, read all lines.
            // Otherwise, go to our last position.
            if (stream.Length >= _lastPosition)
                stream.Position = _lastPosition;
            
            using StreamReader reader = new(stream);
            
            // Queue up new lines
            while (await reader.ReadLineAsync() is string next)
            {
                // Ignore empty lines.
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(next))
                    _queue.Enqueue(next);
            }
        }
            
        // Update state and return the last read line if not empty.
        _lastPosition = stream.Length;
        _queue.TryDequeue(out line);
        return line;
    }
}
```

`GetNextLineAsync()` tries to retrieve the next available line, `WaitNextLineAsync(...)` spins asynchronously until a line is read. Cancellation exits instead of throwing, which is handy if you want to provide a timeout with a `CancelAfter` token:

```cs
async Task ProcessNextLineAsync(LineReader reader, CancellationToken token)
{
    CancellationTokenSource source = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token);
    source.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    if (await LineReader.WaitNextLineAsync(source.Token) is string line)
    {
        // do something with the line
    }
}
```

(Yes, I could have made a much simpler version. You asked for `async` though.)

NOTE: this is *not* thread safe.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I am using csv to store real-time data. So, yes, the lines get added to the csv file constantly. I think this approach might work.

Comment: Storing last read position, quickly rewinding and then reading just what's new is way better approach than re-reading whole data. What if more than one line was added since your last parsing?

Comment: @Charlieface You have to keep the previous line since the final read is `null`.

Comment: @Sinatr Second option jumps straight to approximately the last line.

Comment: @Charlieface The last `ReadLine()` resets the `line` variable to `null`. That's why you have to save the previous value in the loop.

Comment: @Sinatr Yes, if multiple lines are added only the last one will be read. That was the question after all... and the only option for a trivial 'read last line of file' method. Worse, this will *always* return the last line, regardless of changes or not. I'll add a non-trivial solution that is much more useful.

Comment: Ah you're right

Comment: @Sinatr Better?